# OAuth2 not seeing my request in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I've started making an API in Laravel 5. I implemented OAuth2 using [bshaffer/oauth2-server-php](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php). I followed the guide that the Github page links to: it's [here](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/laravel/). I was able to implement everything just fine.

Now when I get a token from the server using this command:

```
curl -u testclient:testpass "http://localhost:8000/oauth/token" -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=bshaffer&password=brent123"
```

I get  a proper response:

```
{"access_token":"ebc6f2cc174f5b6b2ce8e134bc4520ba905c2695","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null,"refresh_token":"b15ef7b5053f3195db7855e499db3af0592154e5"}
```

However, when I try to send a request to a protected page:

```
curl -u testclient:testpass "http://localhost:8000/private" -X POST -d "access_token=ebc6f2cc174f5b6b2ce8e134bc4520ba905c2695"
```

It returns:

```
{"error":"Unauthorized"}
```

Now here's my route:

```
Route::post('private', function()
{
    $bridgedRequest  = OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge\Request::createFromRequest(Request::instance());
    $bridgedResponse = new OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge\Response();

    if (App::make('oauth2')->verifyResourceRequest($bridgedRequest, $bridgedResponse)) {

        $token = App::make('oauth2')->getAccessTokenData($bridgedRequest);

        return Response::json(array(
            'private' => 'stuff',
            'user_id' => $token['user_id'],
            'client'  => $token['client_id'],
            'expires' => $token['expires'],
        ));
    }
    else {
        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => 'Unauthorized'
        ), $bridgedResponse->getStatusCode());
    }
});
```

So `verifyResourceRequest` is returning false. I dug into the library and this method looks good:

```
public function verifyResourceRequest(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response = null, $scope = null)
    {
        $this->response = is_null($response) ? new Response() : $response;
        $value = $this->getResourceController()->verifyResourceRequest($request, $this->response, $scope);

        return $value;
    }
```

So I returned the request to see what is in it. I got this response from `Request::all()`:

```
{"access_token":"ebc6f2cc174f5b6b2ce8e134bc4520ba905c2695"}
```

So the information IS there. But, `$bridgedRequest  = OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge\Request::createFromRequest(Request::instance());` is not picking up on this becuase it's failing. The token is valid. The client credentials are valid. I also tried `Request::createFromGlobals()` instead of `Request::instance()` but that had no effect.

**What are my next steps to figure out the problem?**

One other question if anyone knows a bunch about OAuth:

**How do I send the token to a GET route?**

I've seen it appended to the end of the URI like so: `domain.com/endpoint?ebc6f2cc174f5b6b2ce8e134bc4520ba905c2695`. Is this the 'right' way to do it? Are there other options?

### Edit

It looks like this issue has been encountered by others: https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/issues/576

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with this package https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Add this to your .htaccess in public folder

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]`

Comment: I implemented the rewrite rule and restarted my server but I'm getting the same results: `{"error": "Unauthorized"}`

Comment: In my case, the error was a apache behaviour, that delete authorization headers for security.. or something similar..Can you check if are all the headers needed when you get the token?

Comment: I am using artisan to serve the project. To be clear, when I request an access token, you want to know the response headers?

Comment: No, I believe they mean the request headers.  When the request is sent it should be adding an "Authorization" header.  Sometimes Apache will remove these headers for security reasons, and then the request you are making would fail.  This was an issue I ran into myself.  Once I set up a conf file for the domain that changed this setting for apache, my oauth began to work.